# Run websocket application in server to be accessed from public IP address

Tags: java, websocket

I would like to run a websocket server application with code as follow:

```
import java.net.InetSocketAddress;
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;

import org.java_websocket.WebSocket;
import org.java_websocket.handshake.ClientHandshake;
import org.java_websocket.server.WebSocketServer;

public class SimpleServer extends WebSocketServer {

    public SimpleServer(InetSocketAddress address) {
        super(address);
    }

    @Override
    public void onOpen(WebSocket conn, ClientHandshake handshake) {
        conn.send("Welcome to the server!"); //This method sends a message to the new client
        broadcast( "new connection: " + handshake.getResourceDescriptor() ); //This method sends a message to all clients connected
        System.out.println("new connection to " + conn.getRemoteSocketAddress());
        long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
        conn.sendPing();
        long end = System.currentTimeMillis();
        conn.send("time start= " + (end-start)); //This method sends a message to the new client

    }

    @Override
    public void onClose(WebSocket conn, int code, String reason, boolean remote) {
        System.out.println("closed " + conn.getRemoteSocketAddress() + " with exit code " + code + " additional info: " + reason);
    }

    @Override
    public void onMessage(WebSocket conn, String message) {
        System.out.println("received message from " + conn.getRemoteSocketAddress() + ": " + message);
    }

    @Override
    public void onMessage( WebSocket conn, ByteBuffer message ) {
        System.out.println("received ByteBuffer from "  + conn.getRemoteSocketAddress());
    }

    @Override
    public void onError(WebSocket conn, Exception ex) {
        System.err.println("an error occured on connection " + conn.getRemoteSocketAddress()  + ":" + ex);
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        System.out.println("server started successfully");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String host = "localhost";
        int port = 8887;

        WebSocketServer server = new SimpleServer(new InetSocketAddress(host, port));
        server.run();

    }
}
```

But when I tried to connect to the server, it gave error of java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused. I suspect there is a problem with the port opened in the VM but previously I did not have the problem while installing Apache Tomcat for my VM and can be accessed using public IP address with port 8080.

Is there any problem with the code or the way I opened the inbound port in my VM?

Comment: You're listening on localhost and trying to access that application from **outside** the box. Think about it. Right? Change `localhost` to `0.0.0.0` or `InetAddress.getLocalHost()` and you should be good.

Comment: @evilSnobu that's right! I didn't realize it as I just copy paste the code and hopefully it runs. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that I need to change the localhost address in the server with the private IP address, 0.0.0.0 or InetAddress.getLocalHost() as mentioned in the comment